# Cronjob run same php script many times every minute

Tags: cron

Is it possible to have a cronjob to run every minute the same php file many times?

For example i am not allowed to add these crons because they are the same:

```
php /manytimes_samescript.php
php /manytimes_samescript.php
php /manytimes_samescript.php
php /manytimes_samescript.php
.
.
.
php /manytimes_samescript.php
```

How can i make the manytimes_samescript.php to run many times every minute **by using cron only?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible options:

1. Put many crontab lines with the same configuration
2. Write a small shell script which launches many PHP processes with your script

Comment: "Put many crontab lines with the same configuration" is not allowed (at least via cpanel)

Comment: I used a script which handles the multiple launching of code, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

- - - - - CMD in crontab will run the job every minute. The first star (asterisk) is the minutes column. A * there will run the command every minute. A */5 there would run the job every 5 minutes.

I got this info here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Very helpful site.